# Arch Linux: Why people do not do "make install" in PKGBUILD?

Tags: arch-linux, make, dkms, aur, pkgbuild

I'm analyzing different `PKGBUILD`s to learn creating packages for Arch. I saw in a lot of them, that they do `make` on sources, and then manually copy files in the different places with the `install` command, instead of running `make install`. Is there a reason for it?

Examples:

- https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=mt7610u_wifi_sta
- https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=rt3290sta-dkms
  (BTW, why I cannot even see `make` here?)
- https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=tbs-dvb-drivers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for one, these are `dkms` packages, and the actual make/etc is handled via `dkms` at install time, not make time.

For another reason, perhaps the `Makefile` itself is rather shoddy itself and would not work/could not be made to work with arch linux's packaging standards.

If you check out more repo `PKGBUILD`s you may find more that actually do use
`make install DESTDIR=${pkgdir}`, where `${pkgdir}` resolves to the root directory
that is tar'd up under `fakeroot` to set proper permissions during the `package()`
function of the `PKGBUILD`

Comment: Most likely the second paragraph :-)

Comment: I just thought about another good reason - explicit list of files that package is adding to my system, that is visible in PKGBUILD, is a nice thing to have :) .